# WorkManager didn't work when app in the background

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I'm trying to understand how the WorkManager on Android works.

Main idea: app opens once, WorkManager periodic request created at creation, app no longer needed for user to interact with. Service do it's work autonomously each 15 minutes forever (or until user unloads/force exit/delete app).

I created some code:

**MainActivity.java :**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(Logger.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addTag("Logger").build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Logger", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, workRequest);
...
}
```

**Logger.java :**

```
public class Logger extends Worker {

...

public Logger(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

...

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

... (some code) ...

return Result.success();
}

...

}
```

This solutions work well only when the app is on screen.
If I exit to home screen or lock the screen WorkManager no longer doing it's work. But when I open app again - WorkManager performs all "missed" works at once.

As I found it may depends on "Chinese" ROMs and their aggressive battery management, so I tried to activate "Autostart" and "No restrictions battery saver" for my app on Xiaomi Mi 11. But... with no effect!
I tried to deploy my app to emulator (Pixel 4 in Android Studio). But... the behaviour is the same.

So... Could you please help me? What I'm lost?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue with Android emulators that are launched from Android Studio.  Many developers reported the same issue but all the discussions I came across ended up without a real solution provided.  I have followed Google's suggestions based on Debugging WorkManager (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging).  I didn't set any constraints.  The periodic intervals are always > 15 minutes.  Still whenever the app is closed, the Periodic Work enqueued by WorkManager often stop working.  The issue occurred with SDK version 31.